# Using a dll in a Winform application in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll

I want to know how can we work with a dll in a windows application form?

I want to create a kind of PhotoViewer and I have to separate the core of the application in a dll and the GUI.So in my gui, if i click on a given button i will call the corresponding function in the dll.

For the example:

In the dll a function that permits to load a picture:

```
private void btn_browse_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
       open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
       if (open.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
       {
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
       }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed loading image");
    }

}//End of the loading picture function
```

In this code, the problem is that in this code my dll dont know that there is a picture box pictureBox1.Image in the gui!

Finally I don't see how to nest both dll and gui.

Thank you for your help ;-)

Comment: What is the method in the dll?  You would need to pass the pictureBox as a parm to the dll method.

Comment: If you want to learn how to compose windows applications, this will be useful: http://apparchguide.codeplex.com/

Comment: The code below is the method in the dll that i will call when i click on the button to a load a picture.

Comment: That's not a function. It's an event handler. Big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke a WinForm class (`class MyForm : Form`) from within a Dynamic Link Library (DLL/.dll) for various forms that you decide on at runtime (I think this is what you are asking but who knows), you will need to use `System.Reflection` and do some thing like the following

```
if (bIfDllIsWinForm) 
{ 
    classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType); 
    Form dllWinForm = (Form)classInstance; 
    dllWinForm.Show(); 

    // Invoke required method. 
    MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod(strSomeMethodName); 
    if (methodInfo != null) 
    { 
        object result = null; 
        result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInst, new object[] { dllParams }); 
        return result.ToString(); 
    } 
else 
{ 
    // Else not a WinForm do something simalar. 
}
```

You could could something like this into a method using generics and pass the relevent method name to be called in your .dll.

I hope this helps.